# Nonsense number of clicks from same visitor in GA

Tags: iframe, google-analytics, user-tracking

I have an iframe (on different domain) inside a blog with GA tracking the links (inside iframe).
For some strange reason, we got a nonsense number of clicks from same visitor.
Is there any possibility of some plugin or external code on blog make those weird clicks happen?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without viewing your website. There's a possibility for everything in this world, so either be more specific or provide a link to your website.

You could also use [google analytics debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna) for Chrome or Firebug's network tab to look for __utm.gif requests being sent to GA, in 99% of the cases data is being corrupted because of incorrect tracking code installation and those tool can really help out.

Comment: Please look at http://www.pausaparafeminices.com/page/12 on the final of last post, the iframe (<iframe title="Bless Cosmetics - produtos testados e aprovados!" src="http://widget.frugar.com.br/widget/iframe/133/" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="600" height="320"></iframe>) is our widget with GA.
The problem also occurs on this blog http://cheiadecharme.blog.br/page/7/.
Both use widget from a site called abril, im not sure its related

Comment: OMG, this is a horrible site! It performs 281 GET requests while loading one single page, full load takes about 50 seconds! I counted about 20-30 ga.js requests, no wonder your data is messed up..

Comment: So, when a site has more than x ga.js requests, maybe the results gonna bug?

Comment: One pageview = one __utm.gif request to google-analytics.com. This website makes tens of them.

Answer (score 0):

First of all update your GA tracking code.
It seems you are using an old version of the tracking code.

Also, cleaning up your website and reducing the amount of http requests is a good idea.
Read about some tricks like css spites here: http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Maybe install Chrome, inspect the website go to console and hit shift +f5
and fix some of the errors, also install google analytics debugger like Nikalay said.

Comment: Then im afraid i cannot help, on your part the code looks fine.